# How to avoid dropping items when using core.async pub/sub?

Tags: clojure, channel, core.async

I have a channel acting as a publisher:

```
(def publisher (async/chan))
(def publication (async/pub publisher :topic))
```

Because of the nature of `sub/pub`, when I do this:

```
(async/put! publisher {:topic :foo})
```

The message gets consumed by the publication, and since there are no subscribers, it will get dropped.

If I try to subscribe to the `:foo` topic:

```
(def reader (async/chan))
(async/sub publication :foo reader)
(async/go (println "got val " (async/<! reader)))
```

I will see nothing printed. But if I put more items in the publisher:

```
(async/put! c1 {:topic :foo :msg "after"})
==> got val {:topic :foo :msg "after"}
```

Is there a way to not lose, say, the last `n` items produced by the publisher **even if the subscriber has not subscribed yet**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pub`](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/pub) accepts a `buf-fn` function which is given the topic. This function should return a buffer. Such as `dropping-buffer` or `sliding-buffer`. So if you want your `:foo` topic to be buffered:

```
(pub pub-ch :topic #(if (= % :foo) (sliding-buffer 10) nil))
```

Also see the [relevant code section](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/d8047c0b0ec13788c1092f579f03733ee635c493/src/main/clojure/cljs/core/async.cljs#L621).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/pub) is explicit:

> Items received when there are no matching subs get dropped

Comment: Yup, I know... I just want to know if there's a way to workaround that.

Comment: You can pass a buf-fn in `sub` but it seems to be used only when `sub` is invoked. So it looks like it's not for your use case.